# Why does std::lock_guard release the lock after using std::adopt_lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In the following example, the method `foo()` gets called, where it acquires ownership of a mutex, and locks it. It then calls `check()`, which acquires ownership, but assumes that the mutex is already locked, and so simply adopts it using `std::adopt_lock`.

But when `check()` finishes, the mutex gets unlocked. So when `foo()` continues, the section I was trying to guard is actually no longer guarded.

```
#include <mutex>
static std::mutex sessionLock;

bool check();

void foo() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(sessionLock);
  if (check()) {
    // Do transaction
    // Wait... the mutex is unlocked here!
  }
}

bool check() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(sessionLock, std::adopt_lock);
  // Critical section
  return true;
}

int main() {
  foo();
  return 0;
}
```

I find this behaviour very unintuitive. If a sub-method decides to take ownership of a lock using `std::adopt_lock` (ie. it doesn't call `lock()`), shouldn't it also release ownership without calling `unlock()`? The standard says otherwise, but I'm curious if this was an oversight or if there is a particular reason this is expected.

This could be rewritten using `std::recursive_mutex`, though in this case where a regular `std::mutex` is used, is there a proper way inside `check()` to ensure its critical section is guarded?

Comment: `adopt_lock` means "hey, I've locked this mutex (e.g., via `std::lock`), make sure that it's unlocked when I'm done". A `lock_guard` that does nothing on construction and nothing on destruction would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...though in this case where a regular `std::mutex` is used, is there a proper way inside `check()` to ensure its critical section is guarded?

Yes. Use a `unique_lock<std::mutex>` in `foo` instead of `lock_guard`, and pass a `const&` to that `unique_lock` as an argument to `check` so that it can validate the proper mutex is held:

```
bool check(const std::unique_lock<std::mutex>& guard) {
  assert(guard.owns_lock());             // guard holds *some* mutex...
  assert(guard.mutex() == &sessionLock); // ...it is in fact sessionLock
  // Critical section
  return true;
}

void foo() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(sessionLock);
  if (check(guard)) {
    // Do transaction - guard is still locked.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this Question is outdated but you can also use a std::recursive_mutex that allows multiple level of lock acquisition by the same thread...So every time it gets locked ,it adds a new level of hierarchial ownership and unlocking it decreases the level.:)