# Does std::lock_guard release the mutex after constructed with std::adopt_lock option?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, unique-lock

I know my question is quite similar to this [Why does std::lock_guard release the lock after using std::adopt_lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169341/why-does-stdlock-guard-release-the-lock-after-using-stdadopt-lock), but the behavior I see is not. Here is my code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

std::mutex m;
void fun2();
void fun1() {
    cout << "fun1" << endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(m);
    cout << "lock mutex" << endl;
    fun2();
    if (guard.owns_lock()) {
        cout << "still holds mutex" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "doesn't hold mutex" << endl;
    }
}
void fun2() {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m, std::adopt_lock);
    cout << "fun2" << endl;
}
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    fun1();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the result I get:

```
fun1
lock mutex
fun2
still holds mutex
```

Clearly, the `unique_lock` in `fun1` still holds the mutex. So my question is "Does `std::lock_guard` release the mutex after constructed with `std::adopt_lock` option?". Hope you all can help me clarify this situation. Thank you.

Comment: `std::adopt_lock` locking strategy assumes the thread already has ownership of the mutex.

Comment: But will `std::lock_guard` unlock the mutex in the destructor when go out of `fun2`?

Comment: yes it will, but the `guard` inside `fun1` will not come to know about the mutex state change. You can check the mutex state change by calling `if (m.try_lock()) cout << "locked\n";` inside `fun1`, after calling `fun2`

Comment: @TedLyngmo if that is the case how did the `try_lock` inside `fun1` succeed in my previous comment code?

Comment: @Harry Did you try `try_lock` even before calling `fun2`? You are not `try_lock`ing the right thing. `if (guard.try_lock()) cout << "locked\n";` would be the proper `try_lock`

Comment: I have tried to use `try_lock` and it will throw exception even before or after `fun2`. Btw, this is the official doc of `owns_lock`: "Checks whether *this owns **a locked mutex** or not."

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry about that, it's undefined behavior calling try_lock by the thread that already owns it.

Comment: @Harry No, it's not UB. It should throw a `std::system_error` - and it will, no matter if you do it before or after calling `fun2`

Comment: @TedLyngmo check this link https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock

Comment: @Harry Again, you are looking at the wrong `try_lock`. It's the _guard's_ `try_lock` you should use. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/try_lock - so `if (guard.try_lock()) cout << "locked\n";` before or after calling `fun2` will throw.

Comment: Hmm... I can't figure out how to make this into something that doesn't have UB. I made my own mutex to check if the guards are doing anything to solve it but  [it appears](https://godbolt.org/z/YeTGxoWWs) they are not.

Comment: `guard` in `fun2` releases the mutex on destruction, however it does not magically report it to any other component, so `guard` in `fun1` still thinks it owns the lock.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes - and it will unlock it - causing UB - so I don't think using a guard and then adopt the mutex by another guard in `fun2` is correct. `m.lock()` (without a guard) in `fun1` would be the appropriate action I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you constructed a `std::unique_lock` to manage the mutex, you should stick to it unless you first break the association of the `std::unique_lock` with the mutex using [std::unique_lock::release](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/release). In your sample, you touched the raw mutex when it's still managed by a `std::unique_lock` and this is wrong.

Comment: Oh I see now. I have read the implementation of `std::unique_lock` and found out that `std::unique_lock::owns_lock` return the previous state of mutex (which is `true` when I call `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> guard(m)`). It doesn't know the mutex has been unlocked when go out of `fun2`. Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

The program has undefined behavior.

You've created two guards that both think they own the `mutex` and they will both `unlock` it. That's UB.

Using `m.lock()` in `fun1` instead of using a guard would be one way to make it have defined behavior.

Comment: This is the implementation of destructor of  `std::lock_guard`: `~lock_guard(){ _M_device.unlock(); }`. As far as I can see, `lock_guard` always call unlock method of internal reference mutex `_M_device`. So it will not check the condition as you said

Comment: @HuyNhatTran I guess one would have to dig deeper and look at what `_M_device.unlock()` does too. I don't have that infront of me. I'll delete this for now though. You got me unsure :-)

Comment: The C++20 standard says unequivocally that the destructor `~lock_guard()` shall (as if) call `pm.unlock()`.  There's no exception made for the `adopt_lock` case.  See thread.lock.guard p7.

Comment: @NateEldredge Indeed. I updated the answer.